# Как сделать Slider с разными шагами?

Tags: android, xml, slider, material-design

Работаю с библиотекой com.google.android.material. Нужно реализовать slider в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать шаг различной длины с установкой значения Continuous в качестве максимального?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется можно немного "обмануть" юзера. А именно сделать обычный дискретный `Slider` и перегрузить метод `setLabelFormatter()`, который бы отображал нужный вам текст метки, типа:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
    ...
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="100.0"
    android:stepSize="10.0"  />
```

Далее:

```
slider.setLabelFormatter(new Slider.LabelFormatter() {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        switch((int )value) {
           case 0:
              return "2";
           case 100:
              return "Continious";
           //blah-blah
        }
    }
});
```